# Finding a basis for a subspace with the following conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, $S :=\lbrace (w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^4\;|\; 2x-y+5z=0\rbrace$. What is the dimension of $S$

Is there a systematic way to do this? There has got to be a better way to do this than trial and error. Would the dimension be 3 since $w$ has no effect on the condition of $S$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compute the solutions of $2x-y+5z=0$. 
$$x=\frac{y}{2}-\frac{5z}{2}.$$
Notice that both $y$ and $z$ are free variables (also $w$). Thus any solution will look like
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
w\\x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
w\\\frac{y}{2}-\frac{5z}{2}\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
w
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
+
y
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\\frac{1}{2}\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}
+
z
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\\frac{-5}{2}\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus a basis of $S$ is given by these three vectors (hence dimension of $S$ is $3$).

Answer (score 1):

An ideal way to start is $(w,x,y,z)=(w,x,2x+5z,z)=w(1,0,0,0)+x(0,1,2,0)+z(0,0,5,1)$